# PHP's preg_replace returns null when replacing underscores with white spaces

Tags: php, html, http, get, preg-replace

I have a webpage which includes a hyperlink as follows:

```
$name = "Hello World";
echo "<a href='page.php?name='". preg_replace(" ", "_", $name) "'> bla bla </a>"
```

This generates the following link successfully:

```
...page.php?name=Hello_World
```

in my page.php I try to reverse the operation:

```
if($_SERVER[REQUEST_METHOD] == "GET"){
$name = $_GET['name'];
//testing if the problem is with GET
echo $name;
//now here's the problem:
$string = preg_replace("_", " ", $name);
echo $string;
}
```

the $name echoes correctly but the $string is always null
I've tried all possible combinations like ~*~ and /*/ and [_] and \s and using $_GET directly like:

```
preg_replace("_", " ", $_GET['name']);
```

none of them worked.
This problem has burned most of my day.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `preg_replace("#_#", " ", $name);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) accepts a regular expression as it's first arguments. Neither `" "` nor `"_"` are valid regular expressions.

In this case you can use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace).

Comment: That's not the full cup of tea! There is more. OP has more errors in his code!

Comment: I don't see any beyond missing quotes around `REQUEST_METHOD` and  I think that just generates a warning. There is the issue of potentially missing url + html encoding in the first snippet but I consider that outside the scope of this question.

Comment: 1. In the first code block from OP look at the single quotes where they are placed 2. Also the concatenation dot(s)! (3. And the semicolon which isn't there at the end of the line) 4. Missing quotes for `REQUEST_METHOD`

Comment: You're right, there is a `.` missing. The missing `;` is not a problem assuming it's the end of the file (I think). The single quotes are fine. It's not standard HTML but browsers accept it.

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot. As for the other comments, when i posted this question I rewrote the code manually and quickly (didn't copy paste), hence the missing symbols. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `preg_replace` syntax is incorrect as pointed by @Halcyon, the following is correct:

```
$string = preg_replace('/_/', ' ', $name);
```

But for such a simple find/replace you can use [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) instead:

```
$string = str_replace("_", " ", $name);
echo $string;
```

Answer (score -2):

you can create a function like sefurl

```
    function makesefurl($url=''){
$s=trim($url);
 $tr = array('ş','Ş','ı','I','İ','ğ','Ğ','ü','Ü','ö','Ö','Ç','ç','(',')','/',':',',');

 $eng = array('s','s','i','i','i','g','g','u','u','o','o','c','c','','','-','-','');

 $s = str_replace($tr,$eng,$s);



 $s = preg_replace('/&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;.+?;/', '', $s);

 $s = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $s);

 $s = preg_replace('|-+|', '-', $s);

 $s = preg_replace('/#/', '', $s);

 $s = str_replace('.', '.', $s);

 $s = trim($s, '-');

 $s = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(urldecode(addslashes(stripslashes(stripslashes(trim(htmlspecialchars_decode($s))))))));
    }
    echo "<a href='page.php?name='". makesefurl($name) "'> bla bla </a>";
```

and than you can convert it to before makesefurl function all you need to create another functin like decoder or encoder html command

Comment: If you want to encode URL parameters use `urlencode`. Your implementation of `makesefurl` doesn't cover all potential cases.

Comment: i edited the post. i just wanted to give an example to use the function. he had used only one preg_replace

Comment: I see your edit and your function now seems to does 2 things: transliteration (replace special characters by their base ascii counterpart), and some very strange lossy html encoding. You're still missing safe url encoding. Here is how I would implement it: `html_specialchars(urlencode(slugify($name)))` where `slugify` does transliteration. The most egregious problem however is that your implementation still doesn't cover all potential cases and can produce non-safe URLs. Like the string `"'abc"`.

Comment: Also i think it is not possible to replece all chracters however you can repleace by this method and i know it is not enough but you can filter the data when you query in your db by this method if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9_ ]+$/', $key)){ echo 'there is an error 1}

Comment: That is really bad advice. If you're using SQL to talk to your database escape your string with the appropriate function. Such as `mysqli_escape_string` for the MySQLi driver. Don't do something weird and lossy like `preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9_ ]+$/', $string)`. You don't need to reinvent the wheel every time you write code. Smart people have already made the tools you need, they're built right into the language!